# "После того как", запятая нужна ли в середине

Tags: пунктуация

*после того как станет ясно, как будут проходить переговоры по Сирии с участием заинтересованных стран*

Нужна ли запятая перед первым "как"?

Comment: _flossyU: Нужна ли запятая перед первым как?_ === Приведённый Вами контекст недостаточен для однозначного ответа на этот вопрос.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, законченное предложение.

Comment: Предложение приведено здесь: http://izvestia.ru/news/638716

Answer (score 3):

Нужно рассматривать предложение полностью:

"Он добавил, что окончательное решение будет принято **в ближайшее время**, после того как станет ясно, как будут проходить переговоры по Сирии с участием заинтересованных стран". [Керри: США готовы ввести новые санкции против РФ из-за Сирии | izvestia.ru](http://izvestia.ru/news/638716)

**Составной союз** *после того как* может расчленяться или нет, на это влияют различные факторы. В данном случае часть предложения "после того как станет ясно, как будут проходить переговоры" уточняет **наречие** *в ближайшее время*, поэтому расчленение невозможно.

Ср.: "Окончательное решение будет принято **сразу после того, как** станет всё ясно".

В этом случае наречие относится к местоименной части союза и, наоборот, способствует расчленению.

Answer (score 1):

*Он добавил, что окончательное решение будет принято в ближайшее время, после того как станет ясно, как будут проходить переговоры по Сирии с участием заинтересованных стран.*

Здесь можно воспользоваться таким формальным правилом:

> если составной союз целиком входит в придаточную часть предложения,
>   которая следует за главной – запятая ставится *только* перед союзом
>   [= **не** ставится внутри союза].

[ПУНКТУАЦИЯ В КОНСТРУКЦИЯХ С СОСТАВНЫМИ ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ СОЮЗАМИ | gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3)